# New Install No Internet

Tags: system-installation, internet, broadcom

I'm a new user but not the first time ive had this problem on this particular laptop. I had Mint on it, and it was working, until it wasnt...when i first installed i had to do extra work for the broadcom network card. but when i installed this last time, it worked as the driver was already included.

so ive installed Ubuntu, which is supposed to be good for new users but the only answers im seeing for this problem requires skills I dont have. I am willing and able to learn !
when i open network it shows "ethernet wired connection". and thats it. I have tried running the couple of terminal commands but it either tells me not found, not able , etce,etc. one solution has you opening the nano text editor and writing some script but its above my skills.

I have this feeling something is wrong with the network card. I mean it was working fine on Mint, until it wasnt. I did let the power on the laptop run completely out and i thought maybe this had something to do with messing it up, so i decided i wanted to try a new distro anyway. kind of pointless with no internet. some of the solutions are telling you to download software updates and idk if im missing something here lol, hello, there is no internet!
I would like to learn.

The network controller is `realtek rtl8188ce`.

Comment: First, connect the computer to internet using either ethernet or USB tethering from your phone. Then, open the `Additional Drivers` tab in the `Software & Sources` app. Do you see any wireless driver there? If so, install it and restart (then it will see WiFi networks).

Comment: wow lol ok. I'm gonna have to figure out how to do that. I will and report back. thank you! what the hell, right? this is all about learning Linux so great crash course in network management or whatever its called lol.

Comment: This issue occurs if open source drivers for your network card are not available, but the manufacturer releases closed source driver. For most devices, WiFi is supported out of the box

Comment: ok, so I am tethered via USB to  my phone and I have internet! I never ever would have thought of this in a million years, thank you. what is going on here though? I dont understand how it works? so the phone is doing the actual "connecting" so the network card is bypassed? just a little explanation if you have time. I will now work on finding the drivers, etc.

Comment: so...when you create the flash install, drivers are already included and it installs the correct one for you hardware. because broadcomm is a proprietary driver i have to get it another way? i remember 6-8 years back i couldn't make this laptop work with tails as broadcomm didnt issue a driver for it?

Comment: software updater is working but as of now no additional software is listed under" additional drivers"

Comment: no additional software available

Comment: ethernet: qualcomm atheros ar8152

Comment: network controller realtek rtl8188ce

Comment: Please add a comment to let me know if my answer (below) works.

Comment: `what is going on here though` -- Ubuntu does not have any drivers (either open source or proprietary) for your network card.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Github Project](https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver) hosting the drivers for this card.

First, download it with git. Open a terminal and enter the following commands.

```
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver
cd rtl8188ce-linux-driver
```

Install the driver with

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

Reboot.

---

This method does not have DKMS, so you will most likely have to run the installation script after a kernel update. If you want to don't this every time after a kernel update, follow the [instructions on GitHub](https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver#semi-automatic-installation-dkms)

Comment: thank you. after some more diagnostics it appears to be a hardware issue and will replace card.